# Selenium scripts open a new browser for each script. How do I fix this?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having trouble using selenium on chrome as I am new to automated testing. After configuring the web driver it was giving me an error saying:

> Chrome is being controlled by automated software

So I used an older version of the selenium server and could run the scripts on chrome. But it opens a new browser for each test case and is asking me to login in every browser. How do I prevent the opening of a new browser for each test case?

Comment: Provide more info: 1. What are you exact testing steps? 2. What worked for you? Show code. 3. Where are you stuck? 4. Provide error stack trace. 5. Provide relevant HTML DOM. Thanks

Comment: The problem I have is it does not run on the browser that I have already logged in. It opens a new browser and directs to the login page. Since I did not create a script to perform the login function all the scripts are failed.

Answer (score 2):

adding 'disable-infobars' to chrome options should fix this issue with 'Chrome is being controlled by automated software' message. below is example code

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

regarding multiple instances of browser you can check if driver is already open after test and use the same instance.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am totally new to automation testing and I am only using the Selenium IDE so I can record most of the steps. Can I know where to add your code because I am not using any programming language for testing. Thanks in advance